# Definition of a point in physics

Tags: space, volume, point-particles

What exactly is a point in physics? I understand that in geometry this is unambiguous, but how does it relate to the real world? Is a point particle an object? Is a point in space a volume in space?

MY QUESTION IS:

*What is the physics definition of a point?*

Comment: I would say that a point is nothing else but a coordinate in the mathematical sense

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) consider to only ask 1 question per post.